# User Role doesn't work as intended

Tags: magento-1.8, role, edit-order, user-roles

Creating a user role to access only the VIEW action under sales order, does not deny the user from editing the billing and shipping address in the order information page.

[image]

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your own controller replacing `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController`.
2. In your controller, create an `_isAllowed` method:

   ```
   /**
    * Acl check for admin
    *
    * @return bool
    */
   protected function _isAllowed()
   {
       $action = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getActionName());

       $aclResource = null;
       switch ($action) {
           case 'addressSave':
           case 'address':
               $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/address';
               break;
       }

       if ($aclResource !== null) {
           return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed($aclResource);
       }

       return parent::_isAllowed();
   }
   ```
3. In your `adminhtml.xml`, add this:

   ```
   <config>
       <acl>
           <resources>
               <admin>
                   <children>
                       <sales>
                           <children>
                               <order>
                                   <children>
                                       <actions>
                                           <children>
                                               <address translate="title"><title>Edit Address</title></address>
                                           </children>
                                       </actions>
                                   </children>
                               </order>
                           </children>
                       </sales>
                   </children>
               </admin>
           </resources>
       </acl>
   <config>
   ```

   Now you can enable and disable the edit address screen for users.
4. If you want to hide the link from these users, you can copy `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml` to your custom admin theme and replace

   ```
   <div class="tools"><?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getBillingAddress())?></div>
   ```

   with something like this:

   ```
   <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/address')): ?>
   <div class="tools"><?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getBillingAddress())?></div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

   and do the same for the shipping address. Ideally you put the call to the singleton in your own block class but I put the code in the template file for the sake of brevity.